# How to use params to restrict new posts if they have a certain commonality to existing posts in the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you put a restriction that disallows a new post by a User if say 80% of the words in the new User post are similar to posts which have already created by other Users including the current User.( I have a current char.limit of 100 per post),

In the Views, posts should be posted only if 80% or fewer words are common with words in any other post.

As an eg.if a User posts "The weather is forecast to be sunny tomorrow".

However, if a post "The weather is forecast to be cloudy tomorrow" already exists. 
Since 80% of the words in the new post are common with the words in the existing post the new post is not permitted.

So far I have:

**Posts.controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController


    def new 
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.user_id = current_user.id 
        respond_to do |f|
            if (@post.save) 
                f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Post created!" }
            else
                f.html { redirect_to "", notice: "Error: Post Not Saved." }
            end
        end
    end


    private
    def post_params 
        params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :content)         
    end

end
```

**_post_form.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="panel panel-default post-form-panel">
    <div class="panel-body row">


     <div class="col-sm-11">
        <%= form_for(@newPost)  do |f| %> 
              <div class="field" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                <%= f.text_field :content, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
                <span type="button" class="btn btn-submit" style="float: right; margin-top: 3px;"><%= f.submit "Add Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %></span>
              </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100} # posts are capped at 100 chars.
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) } # newest posts first
end
```

**Various Views- Home,Profile etc.**

Comment: Your example already shows why this isn't a great idea; there are lots of tomorrows coming, and they'll mostly have weather.

Comment: The example is just that ...an example. The thing is how do I go about it?

Comment: usually SO is better suited for asking solution to technical problems... when I read your question I thought of some advanced sql query

Comment: You must handle such things in the model. Have a custom validation which checks for your 80% match, and accordingly trigger a validation error or let it pass as the case may be. Read about http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Comment: Not a complete solution for you but a suggestion as to what to try... does your database support arrays (e.g. postgresqul)?  In that case store the post_text as both text and an array of words created on save by `self.words = post_text.split(' ')` .  In your validate for a post you wan to calculate the number of words (`words.count`) figure 80 % of that (`words.count * 100 / 80`) then in your dataase search subtract the words array from the database words array which gives you unique words, and if result is less than the 80 % calculated select the records.  If  present, the post isn't unique.

Comment: Fabrizio Bertoglio, bitsapien , SteveTurczyn- Thank you for your inputs. cionescu( below) has helped me get started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a personal suggestion. Don't use default_scope (here's a good article on the why: https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/).

**TL/DR**: If you ever want to pull reviews in order of, say, the id, you'll have to do `Post.unscoped.order(:id)`.

Getting back to your problem. What you want is probably to have the post be invalid if there's a similar post. Here's a crude approach:

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100} # posts are capped at 100 chars.
  validates :post_is_unique

  private

  def post_is_unique
    # Select all posts where the id does not match current id and fetch the contents
    other_post_contents = self.class.where.not(id: id).pluck(:content)
    # Split each content by space (**NOTE:** Other data cleaning may be needed -- remove non-alphanumeric characters)
    other_post_contents = other_post_contents.map{ |c| c.split(" ").uniq }
    # Now we need to compare the current content with all the other contents and see if they match
    current_content = content.split(" ").uniq
    other_post_contents.each do |other_content|
      # words in common
      common_words = other_content & current_content
      # If the ratio of common words exceeds 0.8 (80%)
      if (common_words.length / other_content.length) > 0.8
        # Add an error and exit early
        errors.add(:base, "current post is too similar to another post")
        return false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**I would like to highlight that this is more of a bandaid solution. As the number of posts will grow, it will have to search through even more of them to see if the new post is valid. I would recommend you move this validation step to a background job**.

Comment: cionescu- Thanks a ton for your answer. Worked like a charm. I just added ",presence: true" to "validates :post_is_unique" after getting an error "You need to supply at least one validation". Even if it is a "bandaid" solution it still helps get me on my way as a Rails newbie. Thanks again.